# Replace values in a large list of arrays (performance)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, for-loop

I have a performance problem with replacing values of a list of arrays using a dictionary.

Let's say this is my dictionary:

```
# Create a sample dictionary

keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]
values = [5, 6, 7, 8]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

And this is my list of arrays:

```
# import numpy as np

# List of arrays
listvalues = []

arr1 = np.array([1, 3, 2])
arr2 = np.array([1, 1, 2, 4])
arr3 = np.array([4, 3, 2])

listvalues.append(arr1)
listvalues.append(arr2)
listvalues.append(arr3)

listvalues
>[array([1, 3, 2]), array([1, 1, 2, 4]), array([4, 3, 2])]
```

I then use the following function to replace all values in a nD numpy array using a dictionary:

```
# Replace function

def replace(arr, rep_dict):

    rep_keys, rep_vals = np.array(list(zip(*sorted(rep_dict.items()))))
    idces = np.digitize(arr, rep_keys, right=True)

    return rep_vals[idces]
```

This function is really fast, however I need to iterate over my list of arrays to apply this function to each array:

```
replaced = []
for i in xrange(len(listvalues)):
    replaced.append(replace(listvalues[i], dictionary))
```

This is the bottleneck of the process, as it needs to iterate over thousands of arrays.

How could I do achieve the same result without using the for-loop? It is important that the result is in the same format as the input (a list of arrays with replaced values)

Many thanks guys!!

Comment: to be clear; listvalues is a very long sequence of many very short arrays, of variable length? is there a natural upper bound to the length of these short arrays?

Comment: Basically yes, the arrays are quite short but there is no natural upper bound to the length of these arrays or the list. Altough most arrays are not longer than len 20. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your bottleneck is the `replace` function and not the loop. Nothing significant is happening in your loop so you either need to improve the performance of replace or parallelize the loop.

Comment: @sirfz : nope, read the comments

Comment: @sirfz the replace function is not the problem, its really fast! I can do 10 loops in under a second. Problem is I have to do thousands of them.. Parallelizing is not possible as I already run the whole script multi-threaded.

Comment: My point is that nothing can be done to the loop itself to make it faster so either the function needs to be improved somehow or a completely different approach to the problem needs to be done (maybe a vectorized solution if possible?) or something even more complicated by parallelizing using Cython for example (but this will require transforming all datatypes to native C) since threading won't help in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick efficiently, using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package. It can be further simplified if all values in 'listvalues' are guaranteed to be present in 'keys'; but ill leave that as an exercise to the reader.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
arr = np.concatenate(listvalues)
idx = npi.indices(keys, arr, missing='mask')
remap = np.logical_not(idx.mask)
arr[remap] = np.array(values)[idx[remap]]
replaced = np.array_split(arr, np.cumsum([len(a) for a in listvalues][:-1]))
```

Comment: Awsome, thanks! This replaces all the values in just a few seconds :). However I do get a warning when doing `arr[remap] = ...` on my whole dataset: _DeprecationWarning: assignment will raise an error in the future, most likely because your index result shape does not match the value array shape_ Thanks again!

Comment: sorry; didn't get that error nor am I familiar with it; and I don't right away have a clue what causes it. what versions are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7x. Thanks for letting me know. I will do some more testing tomorrow

Comment: Seemed to be an error in my code, working perfect now. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad to hear; is there an explicit reason not to accept this as an answer?